# Is Database primary key 0 as fallback allowed or recommended?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, fallback

I want to use a Primary Key = 0 as fallback for my Application.
Where id=0 means to use System Default, and all above are user defined Entrys. There is no user-access to id 0 and no possibilities for deletions in that Table.
Is it a maybe rare but usual way or should I better never do that.

Edit: 
For usages like:
`SELECT...FROM...WHERE IF(id=0, system_col, other_col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of aspects to this. It's not a "good" versus "bad" decision - it depends (as usual).

Your design is conceptually similar to the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in object oriented design. By introducing a "default", you can simplify the code - instead of always checking for "null", you can guarantee that there's a record, and treat it like any other record for data retrieval purposes. You might also get some performance benefits by not having to check for null (though I doubt this will be a major impact).

On the other hand, you are introducing a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) - generally considered to be a bad thing, as developers have to know that records with id 0 are "special", in a way that is unique to your application (as opposed to null, which is a well-established concept). This is especially nasty if the concept spreads across layers of the application - from the database to the business logic, or even into the presentation layer, for instance.

Comment: Thats a real good Answer.
I now understand, that my bad feeling comes mostly from the bad spreading across Layers aspect. To solve this I have to make precise distinctions where the "default" is needed allone, included or excluded. Make methods for those special situations to become that all straight and solid.
Thanks man, that really helped!
Well at least I can do that without a special Number, but the overhead to solve that would be much much more complicated as my current solution.

Comment: Excellent Answer! I had tried to explain like your answer, but I forgave, my   English is too bad to explain those concepts. I really learned many skills from your Answer which is now my favorite. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AS you know, PK can't have duplicated value.

I suggest that make `id` UNIQUE INDEX and, `NULL` for System Default.

UNIQUE INDEX can have multiple NULL value

**updated**

you can do that without 0. here are my tests.

```
mysql> select * from a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a, if(a is null, "default", "not default") from a;
+------+-----------------------------------------+
| a    | if(a is null, "default", "not default") |
+------+-----------------------------------------+
|    1 | not default                             |
| NULL | default                                 |
| NULL | default                                 |
+------+-----------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not NULL, 0 (zero).
Once created the auto incement starts with 1 as usual. But the first is created with the Database like, lets say other do with properties.

Comment: @StefanBrinkmann You can't if 0 (zero) for Primary key. so I suggesting UNIQUE INDEX and NULL for 0.

Comment: I want to use it like this:
SELECT...FROM...WHERE IF(id=0, system_col, other_col)

Comment: I've updated too.
Ok, thats my Table right now,
Where id should be 0 as fallback:
  `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  section_group_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY name (name),
  KEY fk_section_section_group_idx (section_group_id)
)`

Comment: Thanks @Jungsu! I Think that there is no Problem to do so. But the Fallback will be id 1 because there is so much miss understanding and critics about that. And there are no Database tricks required to create the first system-default entry.